# Get records that have been added or closed between certain dates in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-range, between

My table:

| Column1 | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Value1 | 1-Feb |
| Value2 | 1-Feb |
| Value2 | 2-Feb |
| Value3 | 2-Feb |
| Value1 | 3-Feb |
| Value2 | 3-Feb |
| Value4 | 3-Feb |

Expected Output:

| Column1 | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | 1-Feb | Added |
| Value2 | 1-Feb | Added |
| Value1 | 2-Feb | Closed |
| Value3 | 2-Feb | Added |
| Value1 | 3-Feb | Added |
| Value3 | 3-Feb | Closed |
| Value4 | 3-Feb | Added |

How to get the records that have been added or closed between certain dates in a table in SQL

I'm executing an except command between each date and vice versa then inserting data into a table.
Is there any way I can achieve the desired output with a single query?

I'm currently using this solution.

```
SELECT column1, 'Added' AS Status FROM mytable WHERE date = '2023-02-03' EXCEPT SELECT column1 FROM mytable WHERE date = '2023-02-02'
UNION
SELECT column1, 'Closed' AS Status FROM mytable WHERE date = '2023-02-02' EXCEPT SELECT column1 FROM mytable WHERE date = '2023-02-03'
```

Comment: What do you expect to be returned if a Value exists more than twice? Or if it has the same date twice?

Comment: Please do not post image, use text instead. What do you mean by `records that have been added or closed` ? Also include your attempted query

Comment: @jarlh - distinct records in a date and no duplicate entries in a single date.

Comment: @Squirrel - All new added and closed records for each day compared with previous day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by generating the upcoming days for every column with no upcoming day, then with `left join` you can get the Status.

```
with cte as (
  select column1, DATEADD(day, 1, min(Date)) AS Date
  from mytable
  where  Date < (select max(Date) from mytable)
  group by column1
  having count(1) = 1
  union 
  select column1, Date
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select c.*, iif(t.Date is not null, 'Added', 'Closed') as status
  from cte c 
  left join mytable t on t.column1 = c.column1 and t.Date = c.Date
)
select column1, min(Date) as Date, status 
from cte2
group by column1, status
order by min(Date), column1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yONxKTKw)

Comment: Thanks, @SelVazi. Your query Value2 - Closed on "2023-02-03" repeated twice

Comment: @Siva Can you check now ? Your question was not clear

Comment: I need all newly added and closed records for each day compared with previous day

Comment: Can you have a look now ?

Comment: Your solution works fine. Now updated the question "If a record has been added a second time, it should appear as added on that specific date."

Comment: What you are asking is an other question !! Please write an other question include my query on it and someone or me can answer it